# Rails Cache Permission Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, digital-ocean, cloud66

I have a Rails app (a [Spree Commerce](http://www.spreecommerce.com) store) running on Digital Ocean and deployed through Cloud 66.

I would like to SSH into my server, run a rails console, and adjust some Spree config settings. When I try to do this I get a permissions error:

> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir -
>   /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/releases/20150220220517/tmp/cache/29B

According to the [Spree Developer Guide's page on preferences](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/preferences.html), this is because preferences are cached into memory to improve performance. The problem (I think) is that my user doesn't have write access to the `tmp/cache` directory, and it is my user that is running the rails console.

If I `ls -l` on the $STACK_PATH/tmp/cache directory I get the following:

```
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx 43 Feb 20 22:05
> tmp/cache ->
> /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/shared/cache
```

I figure I need to give my user write access to the directory, like the nginx user has. I tried adding myself to the nginx user group, but that didn't seem to have any effect. What can I do to prevent this permissions error?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/releases/20150220220517/tmp/cache`?

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx`. `$STACK_PATH` is a variable that refers to `/var/deploy/my-app/web_head/current`, which in turn symlinks to the latest `/releases` dir.

Comment: maybe this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1315, what I googled was ￻'default permissions linux'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out based on [this question and answer](http://community.cloud66.com/questions/rake-task-with-write-permissions) on Cloud 66's support forum.

I changed the group owner of the cache folder to app_writers, a group that my user is a part of. The Cloud 66 way to do this is with a deploy hook. Here's the yml file that worked for me:

```
production:
    after_rails:
        command: chown nginx:app_writers /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/current/tmp/cache && chmod -R 775 /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/current/tmp/cache
        target: rails
        run_on: all_servers
        sudo: true
```

Comment: This is correct! Just a note that on Rails 4.2, the path is `.../current/cache` instead of `.../current/tmp/cache`. Not sure when that changed and if it's a Rails 4+ thing or a Cloud66 thing.